# Cannot get my CSS file to override .jsp image dimensions

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am beating my head trying to figure out why my override.css entry will not override the hard coded HTML values for our vendor provided web-page's logo. We're trying to customize it for our site but my HTML&XML coding is pretty novice so I am hitting wall after wall.

Here's the entry in the .jsp file:

```
  <header>
    <div id="logo"><a href="myAccount.jsp"><img src="images/logo.png" width="220" height="100" alt="<sw:tl>WEB_LOGO</sw:tl>"></a></div>

    <%@ include file="leftColumn.jsp"%>    

  </header>
```

Here is the relvent entry in the styles.css provided by the vendor:

```
#logo
   {
   float: left;
   padding:3px 0px 0px 15px;
   }
```

And here is the code in my 'override.css' entry I am trying to use to override the dimensions:

```
#logo {
    max-width: 396px !important;
    max-height: 40px !important;
}
```

The page continuously loads the logo in the original dimensions, ignoring my override. I am obviously doing something wrong and have scoured the site for examples but nothing has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `max-width` gets applied to your `div` because the image inside it has `width="220"` which is less then the width you specified in `override.css` .but ,your `height` of image is greater then `max-height` this gets applied to `div` but not on image ,instead what you can do is applied this dimension to `img` only not on `#logo`.

Comment: @Swati - So if I understand you correctly, are you saying to alter the img dimensions in the .jsp? I need to to use the override.css provided by the vendor so my custom changes persist through their potential updates, so if it isn't possible to aply the new dimensions in the override.css then I may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks to thinking about it from the info provided by @Swati I found the solution!

`#logo img {
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
}`

sorry, the comment formatting is not letting me format this code like above...